# Returning Neighborhood from Google geocode API?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-geocoder

I'm having trouble returning the neighborhood name from a google geocode api. I was just trying to filter through to retrieve it but I'm getting a 'filter not a function' error.

I was thinking... `filter.results(item => item.types === 'neighborhood')`

But I also want to return the long_name of the neighborhood type.

Thanks for the help!

Here's a sample object from their docs:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "277",
               "short_name" : "277",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bedford Avenue",
               "short_name" : "Bedford Ave",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kings",
               "short_name" : "Kings",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "11211",
               "short_name" : "11211",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "277 Bedford Avenue, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.714232,
               "lng" : -73.9612889
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7155809802915,
                  "lng" : -73.9599399197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7128830197085,
                  "lng" : -73.96263788029151
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJd8BlQ2BZwokRAFUEcm_qrcA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
```

Comment: Please share the code that is generating the error

Comment: filter.results is not going to work, if you want to filter something from the results array you need to use results.filter,

Comment: thanks @karthick, any recommendations on how to get the info i'm looking for?

Comment: @Dres, I have attached an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have attached an example,

The result set will normally have lot of address components, since the criteria you are filtering is inside a nested array, you need to reach to that array first.

the following line will output an array of addresses, based on your requirements you can either choose to show all or pick the first one.

```
var address = sample.results.reduce(function(prev, result) {
      return prev.concat(result.address_components.filter((item) => item.types.indexOf('route') > -1));
},[]);
```

```js
var sample = {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4224764,
               "lng" : -122.0842499
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4238253802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0829009197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4211274197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0855988802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
};

var address = sample.results.reduce(function(prev, result) {
      return prev.concat(result.address_components.filter((item) => item.types.indexOf('route') > -1));
},[]);
        
console.log(address[0]," :: " , address[0].long_name ) // this will retrieve the very first filtered value
```